# Unable to bind Json data in jquery datatable with correct data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am learning jquery tables for a report.I am getting api response all fine.But i am unable to bind it to the jquery datatable.Looked many questions/examples similar to this.I am getting json data from ajax call.In my case i am passing three params to my web service.

**Web Service**

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void GetDepositAccountStatement(long accountNumberId,
        string fromDate, string toDate)
    {
        var frmDate = DatabaseLayer.Core.DateConversion.GetEnglishDate(fromDate).ToDateTime();
        var tDate = DatabaseLayer.Core.DateConversion.GetEnglishDate(toDate).ToDateTime();
        var res = BusinessLayer.Deposit.DepositAccountStatement.GetDepositAccountStatementViews(accountNumberId,
            frmDate, 
       JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(res));            
    }
```

This WebService returns this **Json**

```js
[{"TranId":null,"TranDate":"\/Date(1492107300000)\/","ValueDate":"\/Date(1492107300000)\/","StatementReference":"Balance B/d.","Collector":null,"Debit":null,"Credit":17252.08,"Balance":17252.08,"CheckNumber":null},{"TranId":null,"TranDate":null,"ValueDate":null,"StatementReference":"Total","Collector":null,"Debit":0,"Credit":17252.08,"Balance":null,"CheckNumber":null}]
```

In my case i want to bind the data to the datatable on button click.**Js code**

```js
  $('#ShowInGridButton').on('click', function () {
            var accountNumberId = $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val();
            var fromDate = $("input[name*='FromDateControl']").val();     
            var toDate = $("input[name*='ToDateControl']").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/WebMethods/Deposit.asmx/GetDepositAccountStatement",
                data: JSON.stringify({ accountNumberId: accountNumberId, fromDate: fromDate, toDate: toDate }),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#reportTable').DataTable({
                        data: data,
                        sort: true,
                        searching: true,
                        columns: [
                            { 'data': 'tran_id' },
                            { 'data': 'tran_date' },
                            { 'data': 'value_date' },
                            { 'data':'statement_reference'},
                            { 'data': 'collector' },
                            { 'data': 'debit' },
                            { 'data': 'credit' },
                            { 'data': 'balance' },
                            { 'data': 'check_number' }
                        ]
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

And the html

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/EverestMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DepositAccountStatement.aspx.cs" Inherits="Everest.Net.Web.Report.Customer.DepositAccountStatement" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/DepositAccount.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="DepositAccount" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/DateControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="DateControl" %>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TopScriptContentPlaceholder" runat="server">
    <script src="/Scripts/datatables.js"></script>
    <link href="/Content/datatables.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageTitleContentPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    Deposit Account Statement
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="FormContentPlaceholder" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="ParameterDiv" runat="server" class="box box-primary">
                <div class="box-body">  
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <uc1:DepositAccount runat="server" ID="DepositAccount" ShowIbtOption="True" ShowDeadAccount="True" />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
                                From Date
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <uc1:DateControl runat="server" ID="FromDateControl"/>
                            </div>

                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
                                To Date
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <uc1:DateControl runat="server" ID="ToDateControl"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <small class="col-sm-offset-2 text-warning pvInfo"></small>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-footer">
                    <div class="col-xs-offset-2">
                   <%--     <asp:LinkButton ID="ShowInGridButton" runat="server" 
                            CssClass="btn btn-success btn-sm" OnClientClick="return false;">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>&nbsp;Show Report
                        </asp:LinkButton>--%>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="ShowReport" runat="server" OnClick="PrintButton_Click"
                                        CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>&nbsp;Show Report
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>
                    
                  
                </div>
              <%--  <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <div id="DataDiv" class="tab-pane">
                        <div class="row form-group">

                            <table id="CfDataTable" class="table table-striped">
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>--%>
            </div>
        </div>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="ShowInGridButton" runat="server" 
                    CssClass="btn btn-success btn-sm" OnClientClick="return false;">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i>&nbsp;Show Report
    </asp:LinkButton>
        <div style="padding: 10px; border: 5px solid black; margin-top: 50px" class="container-fluid">  
           
            <br />  
            <table id="reportTable" class="display table table-responsive table-hover">  
                <thead>  
                    <tr>  
                        <th>TranId</th>  
                        <th>TranDate</th>  
                        <th>ValueDate</th>  
                        <th>StatementReference</th>  
                        <th>Collector</th>  
                        <th>Debit</th>  
                        <th>Credit</th>  
                        <th>Balance</th>
                        <th>CheckNumber</th>                        
                    </tr>  
                </thead>  
            </table>  
        </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="box box-primary" id="ReportDiv" runat="server" visible="False">
                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="panel">
                        <iframe runat="server" id="PrintFrame" style="width: 100%;" frameborder="0" visible="False"></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-footer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    </div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="BottomScriptContentPlaceholder" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
     
        $('#ShowInGridButton').on('click', function () {
            var accountNumberId = $('#DepositAccountNumberIdHiddenField').val();
            var fromDate = $("input[name*='FromDateControl']").val();     
            var toDate = $("input[name*='ToDateControl']").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "/WebMethods/Deposit.asmx/GetDepositAccountStatement",
                data: JSON.stringify({ accountNumberId: accountNumberId, fromDate: fromDate, toDate: toDate }),
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#reportTable').DataTable({
                        data: data,
                        columns: [
                            { 'title': 'TranId' },
                            { 'title': 'TranDate' },
                            { 'title': 'ValueDate' },
                            { 'title': 'StatementReference' },
                            { 'title': 'Collector' },
                            { 'title': 'Debit' },
                            { 'title': 'Credit' },
                            { 'title': 'Balance' },
                            { 'title': 'CheckNumber' }
                        ]
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

On button click i am unable to get the data and bind to the datatable.
Help Please.

Comment: names in response are different than name you put in `columns` array in datatables

Comment: @Manoz shouldnt the names in repsonse should be like that in the database columns?

Comment: I've put an answer, check to see if that solves your issue.

Comment: @Manoz not working sir...no response..but checking in network my webservice is called successfully and json data is received on button click.

Comment: Do you see any error in console?

Comment: cant see any errors in console sir

Comment: can you check if it finds the node `$('#reportTable')`

Comment: in the elements sir?

Comment: yes, I don't see any other issue with your code as for now.

Comment: I checked the element tab.it has got the element table id=reportTable sir.And i invoking the this on button click.is this the problem sir?

Comment: edited with full html sir.

Comment: have a look at this example as exact copy. http://jsfiddle.net/0xz6gu8k/

Comment: mine data is in json array sir

Comment: why cant i console.log(data) after the success function sir?couldnt find any log

Comment: why do you mean `cant i console.log(data)` in success callback? can you verify if its hitting success callback ?

Comment: Sir after   success : function(data) i have a console.log(data) to verify..running app doesnt get any response in console window.

Answer (score 0):

You have specified column names in jQuery datatables which are different than actual response you receive.

When you pass source to datatables, It must match the column names as it is in source.

Changing column definition would solve your issue.

Try this

```
columns: [
        { 'data': 'TranId' },
        { 'data': 'TranDate' },
        { 'data': 'ValueDate' },
        { 'data':'StatementReference'},
        { 'data': 'Collector' },
        { 'data': 'Debit' },
        { 'data': 'Credit' },
        { 'data': 'Balance' },
        { 'data': 'CheckNumber' }
    ]
```